# I can't turn off proxy on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: proxy

I need your help. I am trying to completely avoid connecting my windows server 2012 r2 with an existing Squid proxy server.

I tried the following:

1. Netsh winhttp show proxy -> answer DirectAccess???
2. In the LAN settings, the automatic detection and proxy options are turned off
3. Registry:

- I deleted the keys(predefined proxy settings) under:

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections
DefaultConnectionSettings and
SavedLegacySettings

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings ( ProxySettingsPerUser value set to 1)
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections keys deleted

4. I have tried to disable and enable HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinHttpAutoProxySvc  settings but unfortunately it didn't help.
5. I have deleted cached files under: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\winhttp
6. I have deleted the sub key under HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Wpad

Yet somehow my host still connects to the proxy server in the background. I really don't know what to do next.

Internet explorer does not connect to the proxy server, but I can see the following in the background in the access log:
I have two network adapters, one is LAN and one is Microsoft Hyper-V. In the Proxy access log it says that my first adapter try connect with second one.

xx.xxx.xxx.01 TCP_MISS/503 3677 POST http://xxx.xxx.xx.02:8080/gofrom/RPC2 - DIRECT/xxx.xxx.xx.02 text /html

Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

1. WinHTTP Web Proxy Audo-Discovery service must be disabled and stoped.
2. Under %systemdrive%\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
   Create the following entry for WPAD in the host file: 255.255.255.255 wpad.
3. Delete cached files under: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\winhttp if they exist.
4. Of course, all registry keys in the above post must be deleted and after that a new start of the SERVER is required. Please first export and make registry backup file.